# Getting Titles of images while using WGET

Tags: web-scraping, wget

I am downloading images using wget for a learning project which i am succcesfully able to do. However, some sites have all images titled with the same name - in such cases, is it possible for wget to read the title of the images in the page and output the images with the title name ?

For example if all the images would by default be saved as 1.jpg I would like them to be saved as .jpg where ImageTitle is derived from the Title of the image.

Thanks.

Comment: In order for this to work, you have to use javascript and look into the html code. That's where the image name is usually stored (as an ID for example). You can use BeautifulSoup to download all this information.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, have never tried BeautifulSoup before. Will try it out now.